# How to overlay a buffered layer to another layer in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

So i have this feature collection data, an .shp. I have buffered the polyline for a 20kms radii and tried to overlay (add) the buffered layer to another layer. but it can't be done. and anyway, I'm sorry if I perhaps missused the term 'overlay'.

Here's my attempt

```
var sesar = ee.FeatureCollection('users/sdwijati/Sesar_Jawa')
var areas = ee.FeatureCollection('users/sdwijati/IDN_adm2')
var sand = ee.Image("OpenLandMap/SOL/SOL_SAND-WFRACTION_USDA-3A1A1A_M/v02");

var bufferBy = function(size) {
  return function(feature) {
    return feature.buffer(size);   
  };
};

var sarbuf = sesar.map(bufferBy(20000))

var nama_prov = ['Jawa Barat', 'Jakarta Raya', 'Jawa Tengah',
                  'Jawa Timur', 'Yogyakarta', 'Banten']
var area = areas.filter(ee.Filter.inList('NAME_1', nama_prov));

var sandavg = sand.reduce(ee.Reducer.mean());
var gtsandavg = sandavg.updateMask(sandavg.gt(50));

var xx = sarbuf.add(gtsandavg)   

var sandvis= {min: 0, max: 100, palette: ['fbff00','b4ff00','00c4ff','0005ad']};
Map.addLayer(xx.clip(area), sandvis)
Map.centerObject(area, 7)
```

the code can't be run, the error message is **'sarbuf.add is not a function'**, my assumption is that because the variable **sarbuf** itself have no value. Any idea how to overlay the buffered layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

You have a feature collection, so you are probably looking to `clip` the image by a feature collection usinng `clipToCollection`:

```
var xx = gtsandavg.clipToCollection(sarbuf);
```

[link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/3998f820d6f41fd271044ba3678b0fce)

---

Are you just looking to visualize the featureCollection on top of your image? Then you are probably looking for `paint()`:

```
var xx = gtsandavg.paint(sarbuf, 'Color', 4)   

var sandvis= {min: 0, max: 100, palette: ['fbff00','b4ff00','00c4ff','0005ad']};
Map.addLayer(xx, sandvis)
Map.centerObject(area, 7)
```

see also another suggestion to not buffer each individual feature but just the whole geometry in [the link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/e0ff97d23de995d34c51463e3a5c1477)

Comment: no, i want to overlay 'sarbuf' with 'gtsandavg' by adding them together.

Comment: And how you would like to do that? You have a vector and raster dataset you want to combine. Do you want a raster output? If yes, which values? Or a vector output? And if yes, do you then want the intersecting geometry as output?

Comment: like, i'm going to apologize in advance because i'm kinda lost with the terms so let me put it this way. uh, i want to show only parts of the layer 'gtsandavg' that's inside the boundaries of 'sarbuf' layer. i hope that clears it a bit somehow? anyway thank's for the answer tho

Comment: see y edit. Hope that is what you are looking for

Comment: oh shoot yes it works, thank you so much for the edit